# how to disable click outside a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the sample code. I want to disable the click outside the search id. Just like we need in pop-up to disable outside click

```
<body>
You can search <a href="google.com">here</a>
<div id="search">
Search
<input type="text" name=search><button>search</button> 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, clicking doesn't do anything, so why don't you tell us what you want to achieve ? If it's only focusing the input, then you can bind the click event to focus the input

Comment: I want to display a pop of search and disable the outside click from that div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:not()` CSS selector combined with the `.preventDefault()` JS function :

```js
$('*:not(#search)').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com">I don't work !</a>
<div id="search"></div>
```

Comment: Better use `return false` instead of `e.preventDefault();` its prevent only the default event.

Answer (score 12):

You can create a div with fixed position that spans the entire screen and place what you want to be able to click inside of it, making all the clicks outside that element actually be on that "empty" div.

```css
.disable-outside-clicks {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.enabled-clicks {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>This button will not work</button>
</div>

<div class="disable-outside-clicks">
  <div class="enabled-clicks">
    <button>This button will work</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also had to add z-index:10000 to deal with some unruly underlying components.

Comment: @JoeLapp that makes sense, you need a higher z-index than every other element for this to work. I updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

maybe the css property `pointer-events` is the thing you are looking for.

add a class to the `body` element if the pop up is opened. let's say you will add the class `.popup` to the `body` element if the pop up is visible. then you can do it like this in css:

```
body.popup *:not(#search) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

this means, that every element (`*`) in the body element with the class `.popup`, except the element `#search` is not clickable.

Comment: Good point Joel, you could make it generic and apply to all div/elements descendants https://jsfiddle.net/bmntvLfs/

Comment: good one. when popup opened add `document.body.style.pointerEvents = "none"` then when popup close `document.body.style.pointerEvents = ""`

Comment: @dagalti, your code will simply disable all elements in the page, including the popup. You'll need to use `querySelectorAll("*:not(#search)")`